# Weird (I guess) behavior of integral3

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate a simple triple integral in Matlab using **integral3**. Namely,
[image: integral]

It is easy to calculate that *I*=1. However, I implement it as

```
f =@(rho, x, y) 8/pi .* rho ;
xmin =  0;
xmax = 1;
rhomin = 0;
rhomax = @(x) 2.*(1-x);
ymin = 0;
ymax = @(x,rho) sqrt(1-(x + rho/2).^2);

integral3(f, xmin, xmax, rhomin, rhomax, ymin, ymax,'Method', 'auto');
```

and the result is 0.499999999999976.

What am I doing wrong?! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the limits have to be same as the order of variable inputs of your function, just change your function definition to

```
f =@(x, rho, y) 8/pi .* rho ;
```

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark your question as solved, so it can be closed